# Convergence of : $1+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}-\frac{1}{4}-\frac{1}{5}-\frac{1}{6}+\frac{1}{7}+\frac{1}{8}+\frac{1}{9}-...$

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I need help with determining about convergence of series below.I had it on my calculus 2 test but i didn't know how to solve it.Maybe compare it to alternating harmonic series.Any thoughts?

$$1+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}-\frac{1}{4}-\frac{1}{5}-\frac{1}{6}+\frac{1}{7}+\frac{1}{8}+\frac{1}{9}-...$$

Comment: Can you explain what follows in the "$\ldots$"? What is the $n$th summand?

Comment: Hint: consider rewriting it as a 'simple' alternating series by grouping terms, and see if you can apply the usual theorems for convergence of alternating series once you've done that.

Comment: n goes to inf of course

Comment: @EmanuelFrátrik Hagen's question is about the sign on the $n$th term. My assumption was that the series is 'three positive, three negative, three positive, three negative', etc. but that should be made clear if it's so.

Comment: yep its 3 positive 3 negative and so on...i had just this on my test..i tried rewrite it somehow but without success

Comment: @OscarLanzi Steven said that already.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Group the terms into trios

$1+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}-\frac{1}{4}-\frac{1}{5}-\frac{1}{6}+\frac{1}{7}+\frac{1}{8}+\frac{1}{9}-...=$

$(1+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}) - (\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{5}+\frac{1}{6}) + (\frac{1}{7}+\frac{1}{8}+\frac{1}{9})-.....$

So that if $a_k = \frac 1{3k-2} + \frac 1{3k-1} + \frac 1{3k}$ then sum is

$a_1 - a_2 + a_3 - ..... =\sum_{k=1}^\infty (-1)^{k-1}a_k$.

This is an alternating series and so all you have to do is prove $a_{k+1} < a_k$.

Which is mechanical and straightforward:

$\frac 1{M+3} < \frac 1{M}$ for all positive $M$

$\frac 1{3(k+1) -j} < \frac 1{3k - j}$ and

$a_{k+1} = \frac 1{3(k+1)-2} + \frac 1{3(k+1)-1} + \frac 1{3(k+1)}< \frac 1{3k-2} + \frac 1{3k-1} + \frac 1{3k}=a_k$.

Comment: and why need i show that it is decreasing?

Comment: @EmanuelFrátrik You don't _need_ to, but it is a standard theorem for alternating series that if $\{a_n\}$ is a strictly decreasing sequence that converges to zero, then the series $\sum_n (-1)^na_n$ converges. (You can show that all even terms are greater than all odd terms, that the even terms are strictly decreasing and the odd terms are strictly increasing, and that the gap between them tends to zero. You should try and think about why each of these things is true.)

Comment: yep i got it thanks

Comment: Did you mean $\color{red}3k-1$ in the places where you wrote $2k-1$ (and $3(k+1)$ where you wrote $2(k+1)$)?

Comment: This shows that the subequence $S_{3k}$ converges, where $S_k$ denotes the $k$th partial sum of the original series. That doesn't automatically imply that $S_k$ converges.

Comment: @Bungo.  Meh...  $a_k \to 0$ and $|S_{3k} - S_{3k+i;i=1,2}|<a_{k+1}$ so that's enough.